# Display different details in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've three Table `Bill`, `Patient`, and `Doctor`.

- Bill table has Patient_ID, Doctor_ID
- Patient Table has Patient_ID, Doctor_ID
- Doctor Table has Doctor_ID and Name.

Each patients billing details charted in BILL table with the assistant doctor. 
However, in patient table each patient general details charted with the SuperVisor doctor.
Doctor table contains all assistence and supervisor providers details with their addidtional information.

I want to display Doctor Name in output of the Doctor_ID from Patient Table not from Doctor Table.

eg. If A patient has XYZ SuperVisor doctor and in billing his details cherted with ABC doctor then I want to show XYZ doctor not ABC.

Please help.

```
Patient 
Patient_ID  Doctor_ID
0004G       0000A

Doctor  
Doctor_ID   Name
0000M       XYZ
0000A       ABC

Bill    
Patient_ID  Doctor_ID
0004G       0000M
```

Currently, I'm using below Joins:

```
FROM BILL b
INNER JOIN Patient pt ON b.Patient_ID = pt.Patient_ID
INNER JOIN Doctor ep ON b.Doctor_ID = ep.Doctor_ID
```

and I don't want to change this. Then How can achieve this?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  I'm a little lost on how a `doctor_id` could be in a table an not in `doctor`.  That would seem to violate a foreign key relationship.  And how would you get the name if the id is not in `doctor`?

Comment: Sample Data updated in the Question.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this...

```
  select pat.patientid, doc.docname from patient as pat 
   inner join bill_detail as bill on pat.patientid=bill.patientid 
   inner join doctor as doc on bill.doctorid=doc.doctorid
```

Instead of getting doctor record from patient table, get from the bill table. This Bill and Patient table are related with each other on PatientId. On other hand Bill and Doctor table are related wtih DoctorId.

OR

If you want to show direct doctor then simple join is sufficient

```
 select pat.patientid, doc.docname from patient as pat  
   inner join doctor as doc on pat.doctorid=doc.doctorid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
SELECT B.*,
D.Name [Supervisor Doctor Name]
FROM Bill B
INNER JOIN Patient P ON B.Patient_ID = P.Patient_ID
INNER JOIN Doctor D ON P.Doctor_ID = D.Doctor_ID
```

If you need the Assistant doctor name as well, use the below code-

```
SELECT B.*,
D.Name [Supervisor Doctor Name],
DD.Name [Assistant Doctor Name]
FROM Bill B
INNER JOIN Patient P ON B.Patient_ID = P.Patient_ID
INNER JOIN Doctor D ON P.Doctor_ID = D.Doctor_ID
INNER JOIN Doctor DD ON B.Doctor_ID = DD.Doctor_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but I'm gonna assume that you have a patient, a doctor and a supervising doctor. To do this, you need to add the supervisor_id field in either the doctor table or the bill table depending on whether the supervisor is always the same or not.
You could try the following:

    `alter table Doctor
    add column Supervisor_id integer` 

This will add a column in your doctor table. After that you can do a select to get the name of your supervisor for each bill.

    `select bill.*, supervisor.name 
    from bill 
    inner join doctor assist  on bill.doctor_id = assist.doctor_id
    inner join doctor supervisor on assist.supervisor_id = supervisor.doctor_id`

Comment: I've used the Doctor table and Bill Table inner join which I don't want to change. The request I've received that, client want to give credit to SuperVisor Doctor, not to assistance doctor. Then How can I display the SuperVisor doctor in the select statement who charted in patient table. However, in patient table that doctor have only Doctor_ID and there name present in Doctor Table. Because of that displaying Doctor_ID is not feasible.

Comment: What you're asking is impossible, you need to store the relation between supervisor and bill/patient/assistant doctor somewhere. You're currently not doing this.